# React Application is not making API requests

Tags: reactjs, macos, google-chrome, axios, fetch

The problem occurs only on a specific computer with a specific browser from what I understand: MacBook on Chrome (last version).

What happens: Chrome is not making any requests to our Backend (REST API). The calls from aws-cognito-js are made and we are able to log in, but when we open the Network tab, we see no API call to the backend services. I tried putting the API call at the top level of the app (App.tsx) and what I discovered is that we only have an OPTIONS call (200 responses) followed by no other request. The person encountering this problem tried to reinstall Chrome, clean the cache, and clean storage data and the problem persists. Everything works well on Safari but we can't leave this BUG. We are just lucky that most of our clients are using Windows systems.

Our project is using React with Mantine. dev and the build is made by Vite. The problem occurs on Axios but also using Fetch API.

What we've tried so far:

- Changing Axios to Fetch API
- Making API calls at the top level of the App
- Updating Chrome to the latest version
- Cleaned every extension of the Chrome browser

Comment: That you have `OPTIONS` displayed and nothing else sounds like it might be CORS related. Have you had them check the console pane for network related errors? What you could do to help debug is have them [export a HAR file](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10358597?hl=en) and upload it here which will allow us to see the exact situation by loading the HAR file in dev tools. Note, dev tools needs to be open before the requests are made, and not after. Make sure they login, refresh, *then* export the HAR, otherwise it would contain their credentials (best you check this yourself).

Comment: Additionally, does your site use HTTPS? If so, does the users URL show `https://` or `http://`. Is this consistent with the machines it is working on?